# Vue and Firebase Auth REST Api Cors problem

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, axios

With Vue 3, i'm trying to authenticate to firebase using REST API.

I'm using vs code and run the code in a local serve with npm run serve.

```
axios
.post('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIn?key=[MY_API_KEY]', {
       email: credentials.email,
       password: credentials.password,
       returnSecureToken: true
})
```

I'm getting a CORS problem. In the console i've the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIn?key=[MY_API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signIn?key=%5BMY_API_KEY%5D). (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

How can i resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should install an ***npm install firebase --save*** to authenticate with firebase